# Drop Hive external table WITHOUT removing data

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

The goal is to destroy a Hive schema but keep the data underneath.

Given a Hive external table, created for example with script 1, it can be dropped with script 2. This deletes the data (removes the folder `/user/me/data/`). This folder has to remain for use in other projects.

A long search does not yield anything so far...

**Script 1: Create an external table**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE external_hive_table(
    column1 STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY
    '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION
   '/user/me/data/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    "skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

**Script 2: Drop external table (drop data)**

```
ALTER TABLE
    external_hive_table
SET TBLPROPERTIES (
    'EXTERNAL'='FALSE');

DROP TABLE external_hive_table;
```

**Edit: Script 3: Drop external table (keep data)**

```
 DROP TABLE external_hive_table;
```

Comment: I came to this thread cause I want to know "how to delete an external table along with data". The answer is in your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use only this statement (without alter table):

```
DROP TABLE external_hive_table;
```

Comment: In my hive system, this deleted the underlying data!

Comment: If you don't set table properties external.table.purge = false, you'll drop the data:
https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.2/using-hiveql/topics/hive_convert_table_to_external.html

From the link:
The following pseudo-code changes a table to external. **The data and metadata is dropped when the table is dropped.**
ALTER TABLE ... SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='TRUE','external.table.purge'='true')

Comment: This answer was posted long time ago and it applies to Hive 1, where deletion of external table only deleted metadata. In more recent Hive versions it now depends on external.table.purge parameter value.

Answer (score 1):

1.Prevent data in external table from being deleted by a DROP TABLE statement.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name SET TBLPROPERTIES ('external.table.purge'='false');
```

2.Then DROP TABLE.

```
DROP TABLE table_name;
```

Reference:
https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/using-hiveql/content/hive_drop_external_table_data.html

Answer (score -1):

we can avoid this steep Boz for IF WE are drop external table it will drop the 
 data will available in HDFS schema will be deleted .
Script 2: Drop external table (drop data)

ALTER TABLE
    external_hive_table
SET TBLPROPERTIES (
    'EXTERNAL'='FALSE');

DROP TABLE external_hive_table